# Reconfigure Netgear extender without Internet connection

Tags: wifi-configuration

My wireless modem recently stopped working over wifi, so I connected it to a router via Ethernet. Everything works except my extender. The extender connects to the old wifi network (which has no Internet access) and I cannot figure out how to reconfigure it without Internet because I do not know what its IP address is. The default gateway of the network I am connected to is 10.0.0.1. How can I get back into the configuration to connect it to the modem?

Comment: Does it have a reset function, as in a button that you would press to reset it back to factory default settings?  What model wireless modem is it?

Comment: There is not factory reset button, which is probable because it is just an extender. I did however, figure out its IP address, so it is working now.

Comment: Just because it is an extender http://www.resettoo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/LinksysRE2000WiFiWirelessRangeExtenderResetButton.jpg doesn't mean it doesn't have a reset button.  I can understand if your specific model doesn't... but we never knew what kind of extender you had, so we couldn't tell you where it was to press it if it had one.

Comment: I cannot tell the model myself, because it is not on the extender, just the series, and I do not have the manual. I have, however, fixed the problem using another person's post I found last night. Thank you for your help.